# why i fail to use addAll method of ArrayList ?

Tags: java, android

code:

```
private void Fundc(Byte[] bytes)
{
    ArrayList<Byte> dataCollection = new ArrayList<Byte>(1024);


    dataCollection.addAll(bytes);   // **error ... can't understand why** 

 }
```

Why i can't add byte array to my ArrayList ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays != ArrayLists

Try this:

```
dataCollection.addAll(Arrays.asList(bytes));
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `ArrayList#addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)` requires a collection as input. A byte array `Byte[] bytes` is not a collection, you need to use either the solution 1 or the solution 2:

1. Add each element of the array one by one
2. Cast the array to list, then add them all

Here's the code:

```
// solution 1: add each of them
for (Byte b : bytes) {
    dataCollection.add(b);
}

// solution 2: add them all
dataCollection.addAll(Arrays.asList(bytes));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you try to add an **Array** instead of **ArrayList**.
You should do this:

```
dataCollection.addAll(Arrays.asList(bytes));
```